# iOS Keyboard accessory view has a gap to the rest of the keyboard on iOS 17 beta 3. Happens only on WKWebView but not on native UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, uikeyboard

I have a WebView based iOS project where the keyboard is not rendering as expected on iOS 17 but works fine on devices with iOS 15,16. Attached are the images from simulator and device.[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7woz0.png) [Device Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTGDs.jpg)

Please help.

I tried setting WebView contentInset in keyboardWillShow() but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.